# How can I remove the H1 option from the gutenberg editor

Tags: block-editor

How can I remove the H1 from the Gutenberg editor so that my CMS Users don't use it in headers or within body content?  We need this for ADA compliance reasons.

[image]

Comment: note that this isn't the only path to ADA compliance, you could also rewrite the tags on render or save, normally people ask this to prevent users picking h5/h6 for editorial reasons though. Removing options from that dropdown is ultra difficult. When I've done it in the past I've regularly found that they were partial solutions, and they broke in fundamental ways on a regular basis as the editor/WP was updated or new UI was added, requiring me to figure it out all over again from scratch. If you're looking for a canonical official answer then that's no it can't be done.

Comment: I'd also cast suspicion on the assertion that ADA compliance requires this, the ADA itself says nothing about the HTML tags you're allowed to use, and it might actually _hurt_ not help ADA compliance and lead to navigation errors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441200/for-site-to-be-ada-compliant-does-it-need-to-have-h1-tag-or-the-highest-tag-can#47162064. Likewise you could also add pre-publish checks to enforce well formed heading hierarchies, or make the H1 style look small and garish so that users trying to use it for font size/emphasis are caught out.

Comment: Even if you remove that h1 option they can still copy paste a h1 from elsewhere into the editor, or from patterns, so you'll need a more comprehensive nuanced approach

Comment: If you're wanting to prevent editors from adding h1s, you might instead want to consider updating your theme so that your editors have control over the h1 that is added. What I mean is, if your theme for example hard-codes the WP title as the h1, you could instead remove that hard-coding and have editors add the h1 in the editor itself. This gives them nuanced control. You would then just need to ensure editors are trained so they add just a single h1 and then properly nested subheadings as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Gutenberg doesn't give an option to remove specific heading levels from the editor interface. But, I think you can workaround using a bit of custom code (both PHP and some JavaScript). If you're interested, try this. Add this custom snippet to your theme's function.php file.

```
function remove_h1_from_editor() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'remove-h1',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/remove-h1.js',
        array('wp-blocks', 'wp-dom-ready', 'wp-edit-post')
    );
}
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'remove_h1_from_editor');
```

Then, create a JavaScript file in your theme (in my code example, it’s located at /js/remove-h1.js) and add the following code:

```
wp.domReady(() => {
    wp.blocks.unregisterBlockStyle('core/heading', 'h1');
});
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work. If it doesn't work on your theme, try tweaking the code accordingly.